# HP 250 g2 - problem with graphics

Tags: graphics, resolution, screen, intel-graphics, hp

I bought hp 250 g2 without OS and tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 / Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.
I am not able to run and even install Ubuntu because everytime I try to run it, my display turns off. I know the system is running well (I can hear login sound), but I can not see anything on my display. I am only able to run it correctly with nomodeset, but there is only 1024x768 or 800x600 resolution. Because my laptop is 16:9, I would like to set higher resolution.

I tried to install official Intel drivers (01.org) - installed successfully, but othing happens.

This is my configuration:
HP 250 g2 (ubuntu.com says it was tested successfully - http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201309-14164/) ;
Screen: 39.6 cm (15.6 ") ;
Graphics: Intel HD 4000 , Discrete Nvidia 820M (dedicated DD3 memory 1 GB) (switchable graphics) ;
CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-3110M with Intel HD 4000 graphic card (2,4 GHz, cache 3 MB, 2 cores) ;
RAM: 2GB

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model (and similar HW parameters) and installed Ubuntu 13.10 with use of external display. Then, I upgraded it to 14.04, but the display on laptop had been still turned off.

In System settings -> Colors, I'd noticed that my laptop display had assigned no color profile, while my external (working) display had some. So, I had assigned a right color profile to the laptop display and rebooted the laptop.

Finally the laptop display has turned on and is still working.